# Add class to textbox in CGridView

Tags: yii

As you know in CGridView there is textbox which allows to filter data. How to add class to those textbox, like: `<input type="text" class="">`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from [the forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9583-how-add-css-class-to-each-input-field-for-search-ajax-form-in-cgridview-filtercssclass/):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array
    (
            'id'=>'your-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
            'filter'=>$model,
            'columns'=>array
            (
                    'ID',
                    array
                    (
                            'name'=>'attr',
                            'filter'=>CHtml::textField('attr', '', array('class'=>'asdf')),
                    ),
                    ..
            ),
    ));
```